# Re-skinned ToggleSwitch animation not working properly

Tags: uwp, uwp-xaml, controltemplate

I am trying to re-skin the ToggleSwitch to look like a valve. I have written a Style which sets a new ControlTemplate as below.

```
<Style x:Key="Valve" TargetType="ToggleSwitch">
    <Setter Property="Foreground" Value="{ThemeResource ToggleSwitchContentForeground}" />
    <Setter Property="HorizontalAlignment" Value="Left" />
    <Setter Property="VerticalAlignment" Value="Center" />
    <Setter Property="HorizontalContentAlignment" Value="Left" />
    <Setter Property="FontFamily" Value="{ThemeResource ContentControlThemeFontFamily}" />
    <Setter Property="FontSize" Value="{ThemeResource ControlContentThemeFontSize}" />
    <Setter Property="MinWidth" Value="154" />
    <Setter Property="ManipulationMode" Value="System,TranslateX" />
    <Setter Property="UseSystemFocusVisuals" Value="True" />
    <Setter Property="FocusVisualMargin" Value="-7,-3,-7,-3" />
    <Setter Property="Template">
        <Setter.Value>
            <ControlTemplate TargetType="ToggleSwitch">
                <Grid Background="{TemplateBinding Background}" BorderBrush="{TemplateBinding BorderBrush}" BorderThickness="{TemplateBinding BorderThickness}">

                    <VisualStateManager.VisualStateGroups>
                        <VisualStateGroup x:Name="CommonStates">
                            <VisualState x:Name="Normal" />

                            <VisualState x:Name="PointerOver">

                                <Storyboard>
                                    <ObjectAnimationUsingKeyFrames Storyboard.TargetName="OuterBorder" Storyboard.TargetProperty="Stroke">
                                        <DiscreteObjectKeyFrame KeyTime="0" Value="{ThemeResource ToggleSwitchStrokeOffPointerOver}" />
                                    </ObjectAnimationUsingKeyFrames>
                                    <ObjectAnimationUsingKeyFrames Storyboard.TargetName="OuterBorder" Storyboard.TargetProperty="Fill">
                                        <DiscreteObjectKeyFrame KeyTime="0" Value="{ThemeResource ToggleSwitchFillOffPointerOver}" />
                                    </ObjectAnimationUsingKeyFrames>
                                    <ObjectAnimationUsingKeyFrames Storyboard.TargetName="SwitchKnobOff" Storyboard.TargetProperty="Fill">
                                        <DiscreteObjectKeyFrame KeyTime="0" Value="{ThemeResource ToggleSwitchKnobFillOffPointerOver}" />
                                    </ObjectAnimationUsingKeyFrames>
                                    <ObjectAnimationUsingKeyFrames Storyboard.TargetName="SwitchKnobOn" Storyboard.TargetProperty="Fill">
                                        <DiscreteObjectKeyFrame KeyTime="0" Value="{ThemeResource ToggleSwitchKnobFillOnPointerOver}" />
                                    </ObjectAnimationUsingKeyFrames>
                                    <ObjectAnimationUsingKeyFrames Storyboard.TargetName="SwitchKnobBounds" Storyboard.TargetProperty="Fill">
                                        <DiscreteObjectKeyFrame KeyTime="0" Value="{ThemeResource ToggleSwitchFillOnPointerOver}" />
                                    </ObjectAnimationUsingKeyFrames>
                                    <ObjectAnimationUsingKeyFrames Storyboard.TargetName="SwitchKnobBounds" Storyboard.TargetProperty="Stroke">
                                        <DiscreteObjectKeyFrame KeyTime="0" Value="{ThemeResource ToggleSwitchStrokeOnPointerOver}" />
                                    </ObjectAnimationUsingKeyFrames>
                                    <ObjectAnimationUsingKeyFrames Storyboard.TargetName="SwitchAreaGrid" Storyboard.TargetProperty="Background">
                                        <DiscreteObjectKeyFrame KeyTime="0" Value="{ThemeResource ToggleSwitchContainerBackgroundPointerOver}" />
                                    </ObjectAnimationUsingKeyFrames>
                                </Storyboard>
                            </VisualState>

                            <VisualState x:Name="Pressed">

                                <Storyboard>
                                    <ObjectAnimationUsingKeyFrames Storyboard.TargetName="OuterBorder" Storyboard.TargetProperty="StrokeThickness">
                                        <DiscreteObjectKeyFrame KeyTime="0" Value="0" />
                                    </ObjectAnimationUsingKeyFrames>
                                    <ObjectAnimationUsingKeyFrames Storyboard.TargetName="OuterBorder" Storyboard.TargetProperty="Stroke">
                                        <DiscreteObjectKeyFrame KeyTime="0" Value="{ThemeResource ToggleSwitchStrokeOffPressed}" />
                                    </ObjectAnimationUsingKeyFrames>
                                    <ObjectAnimationUsingKeyFrames Storyboard.TargetName="OuterBorder" Storyboard.TargetProperty="Fill">
                                        <DiscreteObjectKeyFrame KeyTime="0" Value="{ThemeResource ToggleSwitchFillOffPressed}" />
                                    </ObjectAnimationUsingKeyFrames>
                                    <ObjectAnimationUsingKeyFrames Storyboard.TargetName="SwitchKnobBounds" Storyboard.TargetProperty="Fill">
                                        <DiscreteObjectKeyFrame KeyTime="0" Value="{ThemeResource ToggleSwitchFillOnPressed}" />
                                    </ObjectAnimationUsingKeyFrames>
                                    <ObjectAnimationUsingKeyFrames Storyboard.TargetName="SwitchKnobBounds" Storyboard.TargetProperty="Stroke">
                                        <DiscreteObjectKeyFrame KeyTime="0" Value="{ThemeResource ToggleSwitchStrokeOnPressed}" />
                                    </ObjectAnimationUsingKeyFrames>
                                    <ObjectAnimationUsingKeyFrames Storyboard.TargetName="SwitchKnobOff" Storyboard.TargetProperty="Fill">
                                        <DiscreteObjectKeyFrame KeyTime="0" Value="{ThemeResource ToggleSwitchKnobFillOffPressed}" />
                                    </ObjectAnimationUsingKeyFrames>
                                    <ObjectAnimationUsingKeyFrames Storyboard.TargetName="SwitchKnobOn" Storyboard.TargetProperty="Fill">
                                        <DiscreteObjectKeyFrame KeyTime="0" Value="{ThemeResource ToggleSwitchKnobFillOnPressed}" />
                                    </ObjectAnimationUsingKeyFrames>
                                    <ObjectAnimationUsingKeyFrames Storyboard.TargetName="SwitchAreaGrid" Storyboard.TargetProperty="Background">
                                        <DiscreteObjectKeyFrame KeyTime="0" Value="{ThemeResource ToggleSwitchContainerBackgroundPressed}" />
                                    </ObjectAnimationUsingKeyFrames>
                                </Storyboard>
                            </VisualState>

                            <VisualState x:Name="Disabled">

                                <Storyboard>
                                    <ObjectAnimationUsingKeyFrames Storyboard.TargetName="HeaderContentPresenter" Storyboard.TargetProperty="Foreground">
                                        <DiscreteObjectKeyFrame KeyTime="0" Value="{ThemeResource ToggleSwitchHeaderForegroundDisabled}" />
                                    </ObjectAnimationUsingKeyFrames>
                                    <ObjectAnimationUsingKeyFrames Storyboard.TargetName="OffContentPresenter" Storyboard.TargetProperty="Foreground">
                                        <DiscreteObjectKeyFrame KeyTime="0" Value="{ThemeResource ToggleSwitchContentForegroundDisabled}" />
                                    </ObjectAnimationUsingKeyFrames>
                                    <ObjectAnimationUsingKeyFrames Storyboard.TargetName="OnContentPresenter" Storyboard.TargetProperty="Foreground">
                                        <DiscreteObjectKeyFrame KeyTime="0" Value="{ThemeResource ToggleSwitchContentForegroundDisabled}" />
                                    </ObjectAnimationUsingKeyFrames>
                                    <ObjectAnimationUsingKeyFrames Storyboard.TargetName="OuterBorder" Storyboard.TargetProperty="Stroke">
                                        <DiscreteObjectKeyFrame KeyTime="0" Value="{ThemeResource ToggleSwitchStrokeOffDisabled}" />
                                    </ObjectAnimationUsingKeyFrames>
                                    <ObjectAnimationUsingKeyFrames Storyboard.TargetName="OuterBorder" Storyboard.TargetProperty="Fill">
                                        <DiscreteObjectKeyFrame KeyTime="0" Value="{ThemeResource ToggleSwitchFillOffDisabled}" />
                                    </ObjectAnimationUsingKeyFrames>
                                    <ObjectAnimationUsingKeyFrames Storyboard.TargetName="SwitchKnobBounds" Storyboard.TargetProperty="Fill">
                                        <DiscreteObjectKeyFrame KeyTime="0" Value="{ThemeResource ToggleSwitchFillOnDisabled}" />
                                    </ObjectAnimationUsingKeyFrames>
                                    <ObjectAnimationUsingKeyFrames Storyboard.TargetName="SwitchKnobBounds" Storyboard.TargetProperty="Stroke">
                                        <DiscreteObjectKeyFrame KeyTime="0" Value="{ThemeResource ToggleSwitchStrokeOnDisabled}" />
                                    </ObjectAnimationUsingKeyFrames>
                                    <ObjectAnimationUsingKeyFrames Storyboard.TargetName="SwitchKnobOff" Storyboard.TargetProperty="Fill">
                                        <DiscreteObjectKeyFrame KeyTime="0" Value="{ThemeResource ToggleSwitchKnobFillOffDisabled}" />
                                    </ObjectAnimationUsingKeyFrames>
                                    <ObjectAnimationUsingKeyFrames Storyboard.TargetName="SwitchKnobOn" Storyboard.TargetProperty="Fill">
                                        <DiscreteObjectKeyFrame KeyTime="0" Value="{ThemeResource ToggleSwitchKnobFillOnDisabled}" />
                                    </ObjectAnimationUsingKeyFrames>
                                    <ObjectAnimationUsingKeyFrames Storyboard.TargetName="SwitchAreaGrid" Storyboard.TargetProperty="Background">
                                        <DiscreteObjectKeyFrame KeyTime="0" Value="{ThemeResource ToggleSwitchContainerBackgroundDisabled}" />
                                    </ObjectAnimationUsingKeyFrames>
                                </Storyboard>
                            </VisualState>
                        </VisualStateGroup>
                        <VisualStateGroup x:Name="ToggleStates">

                            <VisualStateGroup.Transitions>
                                <VisualTransition x:Name="DraggingToOnTransition"
                                    From="Dragging"
                                    To="On"
                                    GeneratedDuration="0">
                                    <Storyboard>
                                        <!--<RepositionThemeAnimation TargetName="SwitchKnob" FromHorizontalOffset="{Binding RelativeSource={RelativeSource TemplatedParent}, Path=TemplateSettings.KnobCurrentToOnOffset}" />-->
                                        <ObjectAnimationUsingKeyFrames Storyboard.TargetName="SwitchKnobBounds" Storyboard.TargetProperty="Opacity">
                                            <DiscreteObjectKeyFrame KeyTime="0" Value="1" />
                                        </ObjectAnimationUsingKeyFrames>
                                        <ObjectAnimationUsingKeyFrames Storyboard.TargetName="OuterBorder" Storyboard.TargetProperty="Opacity">
                                            <DiscreteObjectKeyFrame KeyTime="0" Value="0" />
                                        </ObjectAnimationUsingKeyFrames>
                                        <ObjectAnimationUsingKeyFrames Storyboard.TargetName="SwitchKnobOn" Storyboard.TargetProperty="Opacity">
                                            <DiscreteObjectKeyFrame KeyTime="0" Value="1" />
                                        </ObjectAnimationUsingKeyFrames>
                                        <ObjectAnimationUsingKeyFrames Storyboard.TargetName="SwitchKnobOff" Storyboard.TargetProperty="Opacity">
                                            <DiscreteObjectKeyFrame KeyTime="0" Value="0" />
                                        </ObjectAnimationUsingKeyFrames>
                                    </Storyboard>
                                </VisualTransition>
                                <VisualTransition x:Name="DraggingToOffTransition"
                                    From="Dragging"
                                    To="Off"
                                    GeneratedDuration="0">
                                    <Storyboard>
                                        <!--<DoubleAnimation Storyboard.TargetName="KnobTranslateTransform"
                                                         Storyboard.TargetProperty="Angle"
                                                         To="0"
                                                         Duration="0:0:0.2" />-->
                                        <!--<RepositionThemeAnimation TargetName="SwitchKnob" FromHorizontalOffset="{Binding RelativeSource={RelativeSource TemplatedParent}, Path=TemplateSettings.KnobCurrentToOffOffset}" />-->
                                    </Storyboard>
                                </VisualTransition>
                                <VisualTransition x:Name="OnToOffTransition"
                                    From="On"
                                    To="Off"
                                    GeneratedDuration="0">
                                    <Storyboard>
                                        <DoubleAnimation Storyboard.TargetName="KnobTranslateTransform"
                                                         Storyboard.TargetProperty="Angle"
                                                         To="0"
                                                         Duration="0:0:2" />
                                        <!--<RepositionThemeAnimation TargetName="SwitchKnob" FromHorizontalOffset="{Binding RelativeSource={RelativeSource TemplatedParent}, Path=TemplateSettings.KnobOnToOffOffset}" />-->
                                    </Storyboard>
                                </VisualTransition>
                                <VisualTransition x:Name="OffToOnTransition"
                                    From="Off"
                                    To="On"
                                    GeneratedDuration="0">
                                    <Storyboard>
                                        <DoubleAnimation Storyboard.TargetName="KnobTranslateTransform"
                                                         Storyboard.TargetProperty="Angle"
                                                         To="-90"
                                                         Duration="0:0:2" />

                                        <!--<RepositionThemeAnimation TargetName="SwitchKnob" FromHorizontalOffset="{Binding RelativeSource={RelativeSource TemplatedParent}, Path=TemplateSettings.KnobOffToOnOffset}" />-->
                                        <ObjectAnimationUsingKeyFrames Storyboard.TargetName="SwitchKnobBounds" Storyboard.TargetProperty="Opacity">
                                            <DiscreteObjectKeyFrame KeyTime="0" Value="1" />
                                        </ObjectAnimationUsingKeyFrames>
                                        <ObjectAnimationUsingKeyFrames Storyboard.TargetName="OuterBorder" Storyboard.TargetProperty="Opacity">
                                            <DiscreteObjectKeyFrame KeyTime="0" Value="0" />
                                        </ObjectAnimationUsingKeyFrames>
                                        <ObjectAnimationUsingKeyFrames Storyboard.TargetName="SwitchKnobOn" Storyboard.TargetProperty="Opacity">
                                            <DiscreteObjectKeyFrame KeyTime="0" Value="1" />
                                        </ObjectAnimationUsingKeyFrames>
                                        <ObjectAnimationUsingKeyFrames Storyboard.TargetName="SwitchKnobOff" Storyboard.TargetProperty="Opacity">
                                            <DiscreteObjectKeyFrame KeyTime="0" Value="0" />
                                        </ObjectAnimationUsingKeyFrames>
                                    </Storyboard>
                                </VisualTransition>
                            </VisualStateGroup.Transitions>
                            <VisualState x:Name="Dragging" />
                            <VisualState x:Name="Off" />

                            <VisualState x:Name="On">

                                <Storyboard>
                                    <DoubleAnimation Storyboard.TargetName="KnobTranslateTransform"
                                        Storyboard.TargetProperty="Angle"
                                        To="90"
                                        Duration="0" />
                                    <ObjectAnimationUsingKeyFrames Storyboard.TargetName="SwitchKnobBounds" Storyboard.TargetProperty="Opacity">
                                        <DiscreteObjectKeyFrame KeyTime="0" Value="1" />
                                    </ObjectAnimationUsingKeyFrames>
                                    <ObjectAnimationUsingKeyFrames Storyboard.TargetName="OuterBorder" Storyboard.TargetProperty="Opacity">
                                        <DiscreteObjectKeyFrame KeyTime="0" Value="0" />
                                    </ObjectAnimationUsingKeyFrames>
                                    <ObjectAnimationUsingKeyFrames Storyboard.TargetName="SwitchKnobOn" Storyboard.TargetProperty="Opacity">
                                        <DiscreteObjectKeyFrame KeyTime="0" Value="1" />
                                    </ObjectAnimationUsingKeyFrames>
                                    <ObjectAnimationUsingKeyFrames Storyboard.TargetName="SwitchKnobOff" Storyboard.TargetProperty="Opacity">
                                        <DiscreteObjectKeyFrame KeyTime="0" Value="0" />
                                    </ObjectAnimationUsingKeyFrames>
                                </Storyboard>
                            </VisualState>
                        </VisualStateGroup>
                        <VisualStateGroup x:Name="ContentStates">
                            <VisualState x:Name="OffContent">

                                <Storyboard>
                                    <DoubleAnimation Storyboard.TargetName="OffContentPresenter"
                                        Storyboard.TargetProperty="Opacity"
                                        To="1"
                                        Duration="0" />
                                    <ObjectAnimationUsingKeyFrames Storyboard.TargetProperty="IsHitTestVisible" Storyboard.TargetName="OffContentPresenter">
                                        <DiscreteObjectKeyFrame KeyTime="0">
                                            <DiscreteObjectKeyFrame.Value>
                                                <x:Boolean>True</x:Boolean>
                                            </DiscreteObjectKeyFrame.Value>
                                        </DiscreteObjectKeyFrame>
                                    </ObjectAnimationUsingKeyFrames>
                                </Storyboard>
                            </VisualState>
                            <VisualState x:Name="OnContent">

                                <Storyboard>
                                    <DoubleAnimation Storyboard.TargetName="OnContentPresenter"
                                        Storyboard.TargetProperty="Opacity"
                                        To="1"
                                        Duration="0" />
                                    <ObjectAnimationUsingKeyFrames Storyboard.TargetProperty="IsHitTestVisible" Storyboard.TargetName="OnContentPresenter">
                                        <DiscreteObjectKeyFrame KeyTime="0">
                                            <DiscreteObjectKeyFrame.Value>
                                                <x:Boolean>True</x:Boolean>
                                            </DiscreteObjectKeyFrame.Value>
                                        </DiscreteObjectKeyFrame>
                                    </ObjectAnimationUsingKeyFrames>
                                </Storyboard>
                            </VisualState>
                        </VisualStateGroup>
                    </VisualStateManager.VisualStateGroups>
                    <Grid.RowDefinitions>
                        <RowDefinition Height="Auto" />
                        <RowDefinition Height="10" />
                        <RowDefinition Height="Auto" />
                        <RowDefinition Height="10" />
                    </Grid.RowDefinitions>

                    <Grid.ColumnDefinitions>
                        <ColumnDefinition Width="Auto" />
                        <ColumnDefinition Width="12" MaxWidth="12" />
                        <ColumnDefinition Width="Auto" />
                        <ColumnDefinition Width="*" />
                    </Grid.ColumnDefinitions>
                    <ContentPresenter x:Name="HeaderContentPresenter"
                        x:DeferLoadStrategy="Lazy"
                        Visibility="Collapsed"
                        Foreground="{ThemeResource ToggleSwitchHeaderForeground}"
                        Grid.ColumnSpan="4"
                        Content="{TemplateBinding Header}"
                        ContentTemplate="{TemplateBinding HeaderTemplate}"
                        IsHitTestVisible="False"
                        AutomationProperties.AccessibilityView="Raw" />
                    <Grid x:Name="SwitchAreaGrid"
                        Grid.Row="1"
                        Grid.RowSpan="3"
                        Grid.ColumnSpan="3"
                        Margin="0,5"
                        Control.IsTemplateFocusTarget="True"
                        Background="{ThemeResource ToggleSwitchContainerBackground}" />
                    <ContentPresenter x:Name="OffContentPresenter"
                        Grid.Row="1"
                        Grid.RowSpan="3"
                        Grid.Column="2"
                        Opacity="0"
                        Foreground="{TemplateBinding Foreground}"
                        IsHitTestVisible="False"
                        Content="{TemplateBinding OffContent}"
                        ContentTemplate="{TemplateBinding OffContentTemplate}"
                        HorizontalAlignment="{TemplateBinding HorizontalContentAlignment}"
                        VerticalAlignment="{TemplateBinding VerticalContentAlignment}" />
                    <ContentPresenter x:Name="OnContentPresenter"
                        Grid.Row="1"
                        Grid.RowSpan="3"
                        Grid.Column="2"
                        Opacity="0"
                        Foreground="{TemplateBinding Foreground}"
                        IsHitTestVisible="False"
                        Content="{TemplateBinding OnContent}"
                        ContentTemplate="{TemplateBinding OnContentTemplate}"
                        HorizontalAlignment="{TemplateBinding HorizontalContentAlignment}"
                        VerticalAlignment="{TemplateBinding VerticalContentAlignment}" />
                    <Rectangle x:Name="OuterBorder"
                        Grid.Row="2"
                        Height="32"
                        Width="32"
                        RadiusX="16"
                        RadiusY="16"
                        Fill="{ThemeResource ToggleSwitchFillOff}"
                        Stroke="{ThemeResource ToggleSwitchStrokeOff}"
                        StrokeThickness="2" />
                    <Rectangle x:Name="SwitchKnobBounds"
                        Grid.Row="2"
                        Height="32"
                        Width="32"
                        RadiusX="16"
                        RadiusY="16"
                        Fill="{ThemeResource ToggleSwitchFillOn}"
                        Stroke="{ThemeResource ToggleSwitchStrokeOn}"
                        StrokeThickness="{ThemeResource ToggleSwitchOnStrokeThickness}"
                        Opacity="0" />
                    <Grid x:Name="SwitchKnob"
                        Grid.Row="2"
                        HorizontalAlignment="Left"
                          RenderTransformOrigin=".5,.5"
                        Width="32"
                        Height="32">
                        <!--<Ellipse x:Name="SwitchKnobOn"
                            Fill="{ThemeResource ToggleSwitchKnobFillOn}"
                            Width="14"
                            Height="14"
                            Opacity="0" />
                        <Rectangle x:Name="PipeKnobOn"
                                   Width="6"
                                   Height="32"
                                   Opacity="1"
                                   RadiusX="2"
                                   RadiusY="2"
                                   Fill="{ThemeResource ToggleSwitchKnobFillOff}" />
                        <Ellipse x:Name="SwitchKnobOff"
                            Fill="{ThemeResource ToggleSwitchKnobFillOff}"
                            Width="14"
                            Height="14" />-->
                        <Path  x:Name="SwitchKnobOn" Opacity="0"  Fill="{ThemeResource ToggleSwitchKnobFillOn}">
                            <Path.Data>
                                <GeometryGroup FillRule="Nonzero">
                                    <EllipseGeometry Center="16,16" RadiusX="7" RadiusY="7" />
                                    <RectangleGeometry Rect="13,0,6,32" />
                                </GeometryGroup>
                            </Path.Data>
                        </Path>
                        <Path  x:Name="SwitchKnobOff" Fill="{ThemeResource ToggleSwitchKnobFillOff}">
                            <Path.Data>
                                <GeometryGroup FillRule="Nonzero">
                                    <EllipseGeometry Center="16,16" RadiusX="7" RadiusY="7" />
                                    <RectangleGeometry Rect="13,0,6,32" />
                                </GeometryGroup>
                            </Path.Data>
                        </Path>
                        <Grid.RenderTransform>
                            <RotateTransform x:Name="KnobTranslateTransform" />
                        </Grid.RenderTransform>
                    </Grid>
                    <Thumb x:Name="SwitchThumb"
                        AutomationProperties.AccessibilityView="Raw"
                        Grid.Row="1"
                        Grid.RowSpan="3"
                        Grid.ColumnSpan="3">
                        <Thumb.Template>
                            <ControlTemplate TargetType="Thumb">
                                <Rectangle Fill="Transparent" />
                            </ControlTemplate>
                        </Thumb.Template>
                    </Thumb>
                </Grid>
            </ControlTemplate>
        </Setter.Value>
    </Setter>
</Style>
```

Transitioning from `Off` to `On` state animation works fine, but the `On` to `Off` does not look good. What seems to be happening is when I press the left mouse button in the On state, first the pressed state is displayed (Instead of the pressed state of `On`, pressed state of `Off` is displayed), then the animation is played from `On` to `Off`, which does not look good.

My attempt was to change `RepositionThemeAnimation` with `DoubleAnimation`, which has failed.

```
<RepositionThemeAnimation 
    TargetName="SwitchKnob" 
    FromHorizontalOffset="{Binding RelativeSource={RelativeSource TemplatedParent}, Path=TemplateSettings.KnobOffToOnOffset}" />


<DoubleAnimation Storyboard.TargetName="KnobTranslateTransform"
                 Storyboard.TargetProperty="Angle"
                 To="-90"
                 Duration="0:0:2" />
```

**UPDATE**

[image: Current Outcome]

This is how it looks currently. As you can see the off to on transition is smooth, but off to on is not so.

Comment: What's the effect that you want to achieve?

Comment: @XavierXie-MSFT I have uploaded the gif animation. The first transition of `Off` to `On` is smooth. However, the `On` to `Off` starts with `Off`, then `On` to `Off` transition. I would like the `On` to `Off` just like `Off` to `On` but opposite.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

> The first transition of Off to On is smooth. However, the On to Off starts with Off, then On to Off transition.

After a lot of tests, this situation was due to the `Pressed` visual state will be triggered first, then it will trigger On to Off visual state.

I've edited your the `Pressed` visual state to make it look more better:

```xml
<VisualState x:Name="Pressed">
    <Storyboard>
          <ObjectAnimationUsingKeyFrames Storyboard.TargetName="SwitchKnob" Storyboard.TargetProperty="Opacity">
                <DiscreteObjectKeyFrame KeyTime="0" Value="0" />
          </ObjectAnimationUsingKeyFrames>
          <ObjectAnimationUsingKeyFrames Storyboard.TargetName="OuterBorder" Storyboard.TargetProperty="Opacity">
                <DiscreteObjectKeyFrame KeyTime="0" Value="0" />
          </ObjectAnimationUsingKeyFrames>
     </Storyboard>
</VisualState>
```

Comment: When I press the control it disappears. I am not sure if this is desirable (I am not accepting it as the answer yet, but up-voting for your efforts). What is baffling to me is that `ToggleStates` - `On` and '`Off` should be mutually exclusive from `CommonStates` - `Disabled`, `Pressed`, `Normal` and `PointerOver`.  How come, `Pressed` is displaying style mentioned in `Off` state. Also, why the default style works?

Comment: @resp78 The default style just changes the specific control's Opacity, but your style will change its Opacity and Angle.  From the visual effect, It looks like different. When you switch from On to Off, you need first to press the ToggleSwitch control. So, the pressed visual state always will be triggered.